# Alterntive to pagefun for CPU

Tags: matlab

Is there an alternative for the function `pagefun` that works on CPU ?

Example:

```
A = rand(1000,1000,10);
B = rand(1,1,10);
C = pagefun(@mtimes, A,B);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pagefun` is a loop and thus can be replicated for CPU with explicit `for`/`while` or their one-line wrapper/s.

```
A = rand(1000,1000,10);
B = rand(1,1,10);
for k=1:10
   C = A(:,:,k)*B(:,:,k);
end
```

In your case, it can be vectorised as well with:

```
C = bsxfun(@mtimes, A, B);   %or C = A.*B; in >= R2016b
```

Comment: I'll just point out that the bsxfun and .* calls only work here because B happens to be scalar in its first two dimensions.  If B is a matrix and you want to do the equivalent of the @mtimes pagefun call, the loop is your only option.